# vertical spacing between subfloat

Tags: spacing, subfloats

I am using subfig package. Is it possible to reduce the spacing between two sufloats one below the other? I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Comment: Just use `\\[<negativespace>]` after the `\subfloat` line. By `<negativespace>` I mean some thing like `[-0.5cm]`

Comment: Just to help us help you, could you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that uses `example-image` for the subfloats? It would really speed up getting solutions your way... in general.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `\\[<negativespace>]` like `\\[-2ex]` after the last sub float in the current line.

Some example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
 \subfloat[Some figure]{\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image-a}}\hfill
 \subfloat[Some other figure]{\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image-b}}\\[-2ex]  %%<-- in this line
 \subfloat[Some more]{\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image-c}}\hfill
 \subfloat[Some less]{\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image}}
 \caption{There are example figures}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: \\[negative space] works perfectly

Comment: Is this allowed in submissions to ACM conference?

Answer (score 13):

Here's a way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\captionsetup[subfloat]{farskip=2pt,captionskip=1pt}
\centering
\subfloat[Some figure]{\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image-a}}\hfill
\subfloat[Some other figure]{\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image-b}}

\subfloat[Some more]{\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image-c}}\hfill
\subfloat[Some less]{\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image}}

\caption{There are example figures}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The parameter `farskip` governs the spacing above and between rows of subfloats; with `captionskip` we set the distance from the subfigure and the caption. Play with the values; the `\captionsetup[subfloat]{...}` command can also be given in the preamble and so it will have effect on all subfloats. So, you can have both global and local setting, if necessity arises.

[image]