# How to adjust the gap between figure and caption within the same subfloat

Tags: subfloats

My question is:

How to adjust the gap between figure and caption **within the same subfloat**

**Not the gap between two subfloat.**

For the following example:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfloat[A]{\includegraphics[ scale=0.5]{images/a.jpg}}
    \vspace{-10pt}
    \subfloat[B]{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{images/b.jpg}}
    \vspace{-10pt}
    \caption{}\label{fig:online_test}
\end{figure}
```

I got the following figure:

[image]

The sub-caption of (a) is too close to the sub-figure B. I hope the caption (a) to stay closer to sub-figure A. How can I adjust the space between the caption and figure within a `subfloat`?

Thank you all for helping me and I would prefer a solution for `subfloat`, instead of using other packages. But I would also appreciate a solution of using other packages.

I know my question looks similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162824/vertical-spacing-between-subfloat). But **please make it clear**. I'm asking for how to adjust the gap between figure and caption **within a `subfloat`**, not the gap **between two `subfloat`**. That is, the **gap between the caption "a" and the figure "A"**

Thank you.

Comment: You've asked this question before. An edit would have been more appropriate I think. However, please complete the MWE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your have more problems:

- with your code i can't reproduce provided images. they are in one line ...
- problem is probably in images, which have white space below image. to check this, put image in `\fbox{...}` like

```
\subfloat[A]{\fbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{images/a.jpg}}}
```

and see, if the frame is tied width image

- other causes can be in your document preamble, which you not show. for example the following *mwe*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfloat[A]{\fbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{images/a.jpg}}}

    \subfloat[B]{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{images/b.jpg}}
    \caption{}\label{fig:online_test}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

gives the following result:

[image]

- distance between `subfloat[...]{...}` and caption is determined with option `\package[skip=1ex]{caption}`. this set vertical space determined by `skip` globally. if you like to change only for this image, than please add after `\begin{figure}`

```
\captionsetup{skip=<desired value}
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes there is large white space in my figure. I will revise it. But my question is not answered. Is there any way to adjust the gap I mentioned? Thank you very much!!

Comment: how is not answered? gap is set to `1ex`. see preamble, how caption is loaded. if this you not liked, change `skip` to value, which like to have. for example to `\usepackage[skip=5ex]{caption}`

Answer (score 6):

The `subfig` package provides a native option for this, which is the `captionskip=<glue>` option.
You can either pass it when loading the package (for it to affect globally, i.e. all subfloats) or use

```
\captionsetup[subfloat]{captionskip=40pt} % You can use any value you like here.
```

within your figure environment to localise the effect. (Obviously I am exaggerating the value here to prove my point).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig} % Replace with \usepackage[captionskip=40pt]{subfig} to set this globally
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \captionsetup[subfloat]{captionskip=40pt} % <------------ Not required, if option is passed globally
    \centering
    \subfloat[A]{\includegraphics[]{example-image}}\\
    \subfloat[B]{\includegraphics[]{example-image}}
    \caption{}\label{fig:online_test}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfloat[A]{\includegraphics[]{example-image}}\\
    \subfloat[B]{\includegraphics[]{example-image}}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Example:** I demonstrate here the 'local' case.

[40pt] caption skip gives:

[image]

as opposed to: default caption skip gives:

[image]

---

> **Side note:** Please always provide a compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` like I have above. This way, everyone can copy-paste the code and compile it without further additions.